# How to place div inside a div over another div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a div, which has an image inside another div. I would like to place the inner div over the second div. So the arrow in the image below should go over the red. Is this possible?

[image]

```css
.puscicaAnimacija {
  bottom: -2%;
  height: 5%;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" class="puscicaAnimacija" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="second">

</div>
```

Comment: This really isn't a React question. I've converted your code to plain HTML. Please revise further to show the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**
I've converted a few of your `classNames` to use named classes as well as added some additional CSS for demonstration purposes

Perhaps try something like this:

```css
.first {
  background: navy;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.ontop {
  background: whitesmoke;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.second {
  background: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}

.puscicaAnimacija {
  bottom: -40%;
  left: 10%;
  height: 48px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="ontop">
    <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/159/159119.png" class="puscicaAnimacija" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="second">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should put `position:relative` on the second div that refers to the `.puscicaAnimacija` class, then using the property z-index on the second element with an higher value than in the first.

```
.puscicaAnimacija{
   position: relative;
}

.second{
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 3;
}
```

Comment: I added what you recommended, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Put `position: relative` on the first element

Answer (score 1):

In order to use z-index the parent element must be positioned. Use `position:relative` on the div you want to go under.

Comment: I added position: relative, but it doesn't place the arrow over it.